# PowerShell script for changing the identity of application pools

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, application-pool

PowerShell script for changing the identity of application pools of my sharepoint server's IIS server.Am having a lot of appln pools and sites.
so i think, I can write a  PowerShell script and change the identity of old to new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set-SpServiceApplicationPool is for the service app pool not for the web application.

to change for web application, please test this script.

```
$WebApplicaiton = Get-SPWebApplication https://servername:port

$ManagedAccount = Get-SPManagedAccount -Identity "domain\username"

$WebApplication.ApplicationPool.ManagedAccount = $ManagedAccount

$WebApplicaiton.ApplicationPool.Update();

$WebApplication.Update()
```

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/c3e2960c-56e3-4693-bcd2-dc15250bd2a9/changing-the-web-application-pool-identity-using-powershell)

If you dont want using the powershell then you can use central admin and change it. By going to `Central admin > security > configure service accounts`. on this page from dropdown you can pick the app pool name and then 2nd dropdown pick the account you want to assign it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below command:

```
Set-SPServiceApplicationPool  -Identity TestServiceWebApplicationPool -Account testdomain\testuser1
```

Ensure that its a managed account.

Reference - [Set-SPServiceApplicationPool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607906.aspx)

Comment: am not able to make this happen for the user profile synchro. serv, appln pool. even after 10 + minutes, its still hanging state,,,

Comment: any error ? it usually takes some time

Comment: Synchro service is troubled child, if you need to change it I would recommend, Backing up rebuilding UPS with new account and then attach UPS DB to keep content.

Comment: On second thought, try to add the new account as a local admin for the duration of the change maybe it is only that keeps hanging UPS .